# Print entire show path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm constructing a feed in rails and I would like the entire show path for my items to be returned in the content portion. My current code only prints the path without the root.

`entry.content link_path(link)` returns something like links/44 but I would like to return http://www.example.com/links/44. Using the root of wherever the app is being hosted. Thanks for any help.

```
atom_feed do |feed|
  feed.title "Wrld"
  feed.updated @links.first.created_at

  @links.each do |link|
    feed.entry link do |entry|
      entry.title link.title
      entry.content link_path(link), :type => 'html'

      entry.author do |author|
        author.name "Wrld"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

UPDATE

Thanks Leonid, link_url(link) did it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`link_url` is what you're looking for. In general any route helper with `_path` returns the path part and the `_url` helper returns the entire URL.